# How to access sqlite3 on pythonanywhere.com?

Tags: django, sqlite, pythonanywhere

I've followed the DjangoGirls tutorial and i created a blog on my local setup. I used SQLite3 database, since this was suggested by Django tutorial, as being the default one. My local SQLite3 database has several posts. I pushed my code on pythonanywhere.com. Now, my local DB is not synchronized with the online DB, i mean my posts are not seen on the internet. I managed to create a blog_data.dmp DB dump on pythonanywhere.com, but can not access it on pythonanywhere. Can someone help me please with this? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOWeJ.png)
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

I can think of 2 reasons that your database is not available on PythonAnywhere:

1. You didn't actually upload the database file.
2. You're referring to the database file using a relative path. That means that your code is relying on the working directory which may be different on PythonAnywhere. Use an absolute path to refer to your database.